# rails: cancancan seems to be loading a resource from old code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancancan

rails 4, cancancan 1.13

cancancan appears to be loading a resource from an old version of my controller.  I recently changed this...

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  layout 'application'
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    @student = Student.find_student(params[:id])    #find_student no longer exists.
  end
```

...to this...

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

  layout 'application'
  load_and_authorize_resource

  def show
    @student = Student.by_alt_id(params[:id])   #changed from find_student.
  end
```

The above code yields the exact same error as I got before I altered the show action. by_alt_id works as expected when I use it in the console. However commenting out `load_and_authorize_resource` leads to a different error: the view tells me that @student is nil.

What am I not understanding here? Why does it appear that my app is running old code?

Comment: since rails 4 try `@student = Student.where(id: params[:id])`. But if you specify   `load_and_authorize_resource`, you can remove this line from show action.